# MongoClient failed to connect to server on first connect, but connects later

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am very confused about how `MongoClient.connect` is supposed to be used. I have an express app that uses MongoDB and I'm working on deploying it with docker. When using `docker-compose up`, the app might try to connect to mongo before mongo is ready to accept connections. When this happens, I get the following error:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:27017]
```

That's fine, but it actually connects as soon the database is available. That would also be fine, but the promise is already rejected and I don't have anyway of using that connection. I also tried switching to using callbacks, but the callback is never called again after the failure.

I can always retry until I get a working connection without an error, but for every time I retry, I get another connection to the database that isn't closed until the application restarts, which normally is when a new version is deployed.

I either need a way to use the connection that initially failed or stop the failed connections from retrying. Does anyone have a clue how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The 3.0 version of the Node.js MongoDB driver gives you some additional flexibility here as you can create your own [`MongoClient`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html) object and use its methods to connect, check if you're still connected, and disconnect as needed:

```
let mc = new mongodb.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost');

await mc.connect();

if (mc.isConnected()) { ... }

let db = mc.db('test');
let collection = db.collection("test");

...

await mc.close();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. It seems like even `MongoClient` doesn't realise that it has connected. `mc.isConnected()` returns `false` even after the connection shows up in the log. I will keep trying. At least now I have a reference to the client that made the connection, maybe I can do something with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're starting your containers all at once, the MongoDB container might not be up before your app container.

You can [Control startup order in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) to ensure that the MongoDB container is up before the app container, e.g. by using the `depends_on` directive. From an example on the linked page:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: mongodb
```

However note that as mentioned in the [depends_on documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on), it is not a complete solution since it only waits until the container is started, not necessarily until the database is started.

You would need to use `depends_on` in combination with a script like [wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) to ensure the database is actually up.

Comment: This solves my problem, but it doesn't change the fact that the `MongoClient` is leaking connections when it fails to connect. The only way to avoid the leak is to kill the process and restart it. It would be nice if I could have my app running, so that APIs that don't depend on MongoDB can continue to function and the ones that do can return an appropriate error message.